# I keep getting a naive date warning even though my model default uses timezoned date

Tags: python, django

Every time I run `python manage.py test` I get a warning saying that my model fields recived naive datetime:

```
(venv) C:\Users\Philip\CodeRepos\Acacia2>python manage.py test journal.tests.test_models    
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
C:\Users\Philip\CodeRepos\Acacia2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py:1365: RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField Ledger.last_spreadsheet_update received a naive datetime (1970-01-01 00:00:00) while time zone support is active.
  warnings.warn("DateTimeField %s received a naive datetime (%s)"
C:\Users\Philip\CodeRepos\Acacia2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py:1365: RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField JournalEntry.last_integrity_check received a naive datetime (1970-01-01 00:00:00) while time zone support is active.
  warnings.warn("DateTimeField %s received a naive datetime (%s)"
```

However my models are configured with a default datetime that includes a timezone:

```
class Ledger(models.Model):
    sort = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, blank=False, null=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    coa_sub_group = models.ForeignKey(COASubGroup, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    is_reconcilable = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    spreadsheet_row = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
    last_spreadsheet_update = models.DateTimeField(blank=False, null=False, default=datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=timezone('UTC')))

class JournalEntry(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=False, blank=False)
    date = models.DateField(null=False, blank=False)
    # Data integrity check fields
    last_integrity_check = models.DateTimeField(blank=False, null=False, default=datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=timezone('UTC')))
    integrity_check_fail = models.BooleanField(null=False, blank=False, default=0)
```

What could I be doing wrong?

`python manage.py diffsettings` gives:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
```

Comment: What version of django are you using.?

perhaps you ran `python manage.py diff_settings` an dyou look at the time zone related settings.

Comment: I'm using latest Django. I just edited and posted python manage.py diffsettings output.